# Using custom Tag files in JSP with Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp-tags

I have a Spring Boot project and I'm trying to make the following call in a JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tagz" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<tagz:utils tabs="true"/>
```

The tags folder is in -

> \src\main\resources\WEB-INF\tags

The JSP files folder is in -

> \src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\jsp

I also defined the application.properties file to include:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

If I try to put the tags folder in any other classpath than Intellij is showing an error that It cannot identify the call in the editor.

The JSP page is presented properly if I remove the taglib call.

My pom.xml is of course has these dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Jun 25 16:12:47 IDT 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). /WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp
>   (line: [11], column: [4]) No tag [utils] defined in tag library
>   imported with prefix [tagz]

I think It has to do with configuration of static files in Spring Boot but I tried to add 
spring.resources.static-

```
locations=classpath:/resources/static/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/WEB-INF/tags/,classpath:/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Nothing seems to work.
I should mention that these taglibs are working properly!

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Any help?

Comment: I suppose this error was thrown over server console not IDE.Are u using some tag with name 'tagz'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a lot of trail and error I now put all my JSP files inside of path:

```
webapp/WEB-INF/jsp
```

Tags files inside of:

```
webapp/WEB-INF/tags
```

And Tlds files inside of:

```
webapp/WEB-INF/tld
```

When you call the tag/tld files you inside of the JSPs you need to refer them to relative path e.g:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ui" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/ui" %>
```

You will also need to define a Facet in project structure. If you don't have it define that means that you need to generate it by adding "web framework" to your project. It will generate web.xml and you need to put it under `webapp/WEB-INF` and edit it in project Facets manaully.

Hope this will help anyone who sees this post.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem. I have tried adding the files under /src/main/resources/META-INF/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp and /src/main/resources/META-INF/webapp/WEB-INF/tld, but this has made no difference. If possible, could you confirm the full file structure that fixed the issue on your side? Thank you.

Comment: These are the complete paths:

{MY-APP}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp
{MY-APP}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags
{MY-APP}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tlds

It's not supposed to be in the META-INF from what I've tried.

Comment: Omg, man, you saved me. I just wasted a whole day trying to figure out why my .tag wasn't getting picked up. It was originaly in /src/main/etc/tag, configured that after compilation it would copied to /target/classes/web-inf/tag by eclipse. I read your answer and just went with your solution, reorganized my sources to contain directly web-inf/tag and it worked. And it's not that eclipse was messing up the execution env, mvn spring-boot:run from cmd was failing too. such an annoying and stupid inconsistency...

Comment: Thanks for the details, got a nutty error message: [tagdir does not start with /WEB-INF/tags]. In my book, if the system requires tags to be in a specific directory, then we should not have to specify that directory. Sigh...